# How does bit64 store long long int in a double

Tags: r, int64

When storing a whole number as a double, loss of precision stars occurring after 2^53:

```
> print(2^53, digits=20)
[1] 9007199254740992
> print(2^53+1, digits=20)
[1] 9007199254740992
```

The [bit64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) package in R can store integers up to 2^63:

```
> library(bit64)
> print(as.integer64(2)^53, digits=20)
[1] 9007199254740992
> print(as.integer64(2)^53+1, digits=20)
[1] 9007199254740993
```

However it looks like integer64 objects are just doubles dressed up with a special class:

```
> typeof(as.integer64(2)^53)
[1] "double"
```

How is it possible that a 32 bit double can store a 64 bit integer?

Comment: bit64 defines a `+.integer64` method. That's the difference between your two examples.

Comment: @mdsumner even on x86 architectuers?

Comment: Yes. It is what 'double' means. 2*4 bytes as opposed to 'single'. R has no 32-bit floating point type off the shelf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in a search I did and I was able to find the answer.

As [mdsumner commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795212/how-does-bit64-store-long-long-int-in-a-double#comment42345150_26795212), a double is 64-bit by definition.  Doubles are stored in R's `REALSXP` type. 
The bit64 package converts the input from its various `integer64` methods to `uint64_t` (which is supported by C99) and stores the 64-bits in R's `REALSXP`.